# use os.system('MyCommand') in the next command

Tags: python, python-3.x

As far as you know, we can use OS console commands, (For example `dir`,`time` and `format` in Windows) in Python programing using `os.system('TheCommand')` module. But this function return the state of Operation (`0` for successful and `1` for failed).

I want to know if is there any way to use the output of the commands in the next commands? I mean (For example) I run `os.system('dir')` and save the list of directories in a variable!

Comment: Why don't you use `os.listdir` instead of making a console call?

Comment: Might also be worth nothing that system calls should probably be made with the newer `subprocess` module unless supporting backward compatible versions of python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The `dir` was just an example. I want to use all another commands too

Comment: In that case, @alexwlchan’s comment is correct. I’ll close this question then. Just remember to check if there might not be library functions that already do the job, since you stay platform-independent that way.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output?

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly easy to do. Here I define the working directory and the edit time of a file as variables which I used later in my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

PWD = os.getcwd()
edit_time=os.path.getmtime(file.txt)
```